# Begin comparison after partial string match javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, array-splice

The following function is intended to receive a partial URL as user input, run it against a data set of URLS, and return matches.

For example, if a user inputs "/parentfolder/articlename/", how can I retrieve a match against https://sitename.com/countrycode/parentfolder/articlename/?

The function below is currently using the slice method to start the comparison after a certain index, but the problem with this is that the countrycode in the example url is of variable length. I've also included a sample data set for reference.

```
function lookForMatches(){
  const slugName = `${slugData.slug()}`;
  for (var i = 0; i < globalArticles.length; i++) {
    if(slugName === globalArticles[i]["slug"].slice(37)){
      const showMatches = document.createElement('div')
      showMatches.innerHTML = (`<p>${globalArticles[i]["language"]}: ${globalArticles[i]["slug"]}<p>`);
      document.getElementById("slugResults").appendChild(showMatches);
    }
    else {
      const noMatches = document.createElement('div');
      noMatches.innerHTML = `<p>No translations found for ${globalArticles[i]["language"]}</p>`;
      document.getElementById("slugResults").appendChild(noMatches);

    }
  }

const globalArticles =
[
  {
    language: "Deutsch",
    slug: "https://sitename.com/countrycode/parentfolder/articlename/"
  },

  {
    language: "Svenksa",
    slug: "https://sitename.com/countrycode/parentfolder/articlename/"
  }
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please include example data for input and what your expecting for output. Also, as you have existing code, what you are getting instead of the expected output.

Comment: Can you not just count the forward slashes instead of looking at a set index? Another alternative is regex?

Comment: I've included a sample data set. As of now, I get the expected result using the splice method since the data ive included has the same length up to /parentfolder. However, /countrycodes/ will not have the same length in every case, so this method will not work for all use cases

Comment: What you want is regexp. It is meant to find patterns in string.

Comment: I figured regex might work but not too familiar. Could you demonstrate what that might look like?